# How to set the position of showing tooltip in wfa C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a form in wfa C#. I stuck in one place. How to set the position of toolltip that it shows perfect above and under the textboox "PESEL"?
Above view:
[image]

Under view:
[image]

The code for toolltip:

```
toolTip1.Show(string.Empty, textBox3, 0);
toolTip1.Show("Akceptowane są tylko cyfry", textBox3, textBox3.Width / 2, textBox3.Height, 5000);
```

Comment: Not clear. How is possible to have the tooltip _above_ and _under_ the control?

Comment: In the first photo the ballon is under far under the textbox I just want that it shows perfet above the textbox "Pesel" and under the textbox PESEL.

Comment: It's perfect when I set IsBaloon = false;

Comment: I'm guessing that _"wfa"_ is Windows Forms Something.  Is that correct, or is there another meaning?

Comment: Yes Windows form application

Comment: found sth like that https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Dorababu742/using-tooltip-control-in-windows-form/

Comment: Do you mean "I want to position this tool tip directly under a specific control" but also "I want the _'tail'_ on the balloon to point up at the control (like what you have (I'm guessing) prototyped in your second image).  Is that what you mean?

Comment: OK I found solution I just removed the line "toolTip1.Show(string.Empty, textBox3, 0);" Now it;s showing perfect under the textbox